# Update Page With Values Before Continuing Loop

Tags: javascript, html

I've created some code that will round entered numbers either up or down, depending on if the whole number is even or odd. I've got that out of the way, however now I would like to place my code into a loop that will continuously prompt a user to enter another number until they enter a value like "x".

What I would like to happen is for the page to update with the calculated values before prompting the user again. I have not been able to figure how to do this yet, hence my question here.

Is there even a way to do this or am I going about it all wrong?

Javascript:

```
function main() {
    var n = prompt("Enter A Number\nCan Be A Whole Number Or Decimal Number With One Decimal Place.\nOr Enter x To Exit.");
        while (n != "x") {
            var nn = 0
            if (n.includes(".")) {
                var n = parseFloat(n);
                q = Math.trunc(n);
                if (q % 5 == 0) {
                    if ((n % 1) >= 0.5) {
                        nn = (Math.ceil(n));
                    } else if ((n % 1) < 0.5) {
                        nn = (Math.floor(n));
                    }
                } else {
                    if ((n % 1) <= 0.5) {
                        nn = (Math.floor(n));
                    } else if ((n % 1) > 0.5) {
                        nn = (Math.ceil(n));
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("orgNum").innerHTML = "Original Number: " + n;
            document.getElementById("roundNum").innerHTML = "Rounded Number: " + nn
            setTimeout(main, 5000);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("orgNum").innerHTML = "Original Number: " + n;
            document.getElementById("roundNum").innerHTML = "Rounded Number: Whole Number Was Entered."
            setTimeout(main, 5000);


    }
    setTimeout(main, 5000);
    var n = prompt("Enter Another Number\nCan Be A Whole Number Or Decimal Number With One Decimal Place.\nOr Enter x To Exit.")

    }
```

}

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="dataEntry">
        <input type="button" id="subButton" value="Begin" onClick="main()">
    </div>
    <div id="dataPrint">
        <p id="orgNum">Original Number: </p>
        <p id="roundNum">Rounded Number: </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript in the browser runs in a single thread along with the ui. Taking over that thread with a loop, as your code attempts to do, would block the ui from functioning, including allowing the user to enter text in the input.

Instead of your while loop, you need to use event listeners.

You could attach an onkeyup event listener to your input, which looks for the enter key (keycode 13), or put your input into a form and attach an onsubmit event listener to the form.

This event listener will look for an 'x' character in the input field: if it finds it, you're done (you could hide the input and/or put a message on the page indicating that no more input is required).

If you don't find the x, do your rounding and clear the input value. After you do the rounding/clear, the user will be able to enter another value, press enter, which triggers the event listener again, and so on until the 'x' is detected.

This link should help:

[Element: keyup event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event#Examples)

Comment: Thanks Mark, I had a feeling I wouldn't be able to with my code the way it is currently. Adding event listeners does what I need the code to do, so thanks.

Comment: Good to hear that it helped. And let us know if you need more assistance with writing the code